# Multiplatform Git server

Tags: git

I am looking for some git server for more platforms, such as Windows, Linux and Solaris.
I know only msysgit for win. Is there some equivalent for these three platforms?

Comment: You can use an HTTP server on Windows or many other systems, but Git is built to run on *nix systems nativelly. You have to just install it and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes **"GIT"** its independent and written in C/C++. There are git client for all plattforms.
But its a bit difficult what you understand under a "GIT -Server". Every client that has the repository can be the server when you add them as remote server.

On Ubuntu and Debian:

```
apt-get install git-core
```

On Mac something like this:

```
sudo port install git-core
```

If there is no client you can compile the sources.

But its a very common question. Google at first.

Edit: You don't have a server directly. You put the repository on a server for example and access them from outside. For example you can make bare repositories this creates a folder for example "test.git" then you can call the file over ssh or other access methods.

But perhaps you should think about a gitkeeper like "gitolite" to give access to user and control the flow and provide the repositories.

But how @rcdmk said its primary build for linux and unix systems.

Comment: I am looking for git server to setup my own git server, not git client. Is this "git-core" source code of git server (like compiled msysgit)?

Comment: I [very much doubt](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/linus) Git contains a single bit of C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Git Candy, A Git platform based on ASP.NET MVC.

Source on: http://github.com/Aimeast/GitCandy

Demo on: http://gitcandy.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is an all in one open-source solution equivalent of GitHub written in Java called GitBlit.

http://gitblit.com/